# Electron-packager: can not locate local db file after packing

Tags: sqlite, electron, electron-packager

**Background:**
In my app, I have a local DB file, named `example.db` which is read by the `main.js`. The project structure and part of my `main.js` program is shown below.

**Project folder architecture**

[image]

**main.js**

```
const {
  app,
  BrowserWindow,
  dialog,
  Menu
} = require('electron')

const fs = require('fs')
const path = require('path')

const sqlite3 = require('sqlite3').verbose()

// load dataBase
let dbFile = 'app/db/example.db'
const db = new sqlite3.Database(dbFile)
```

**Package.json**

```
{
  "name": "Example",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "./app/main.js",
  "scripts": {
    "postinstall": "install-app-deps",
    "start": "electron ."
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "electron-builder": "^15.5.1",
    "electron-prebuilt": "^1.4",
    "electron-rebuild": "^1.5.7",
    "electron-packager": "^8.1.0"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "jquery": "^3.1.1",
    "sqlite3": "^3.1.8"
  }
}
```

**Problems:**

I can load the DB file successfully by running the `npm start`, however, after I successfully packing my program to Windows platform by running the following command line under `Example` folder:

`node_modules/.bin/electron-packager --platform=win32 --arch=x64 .`

I ran the `.exe` file, but the system shows that it can not find my Database file.

[image]

**Tried methods:**

I tried to modify the db filepath in the `main.js` by using `process.resourscesPath` as the following:

```
// load dataBase
let dbFile = path.join(process.resourcesPath, '/app/db/example.db')
const db = new sqlite3.Database(dbFile)
```

However, after doing that, I neither can load the DB file from running `.exe`, nor can I make it by running `npm start`.

**Question:**

I want to what is the proper way to store my Database file, and how to write the path of it in my back-end program (`main.js` in this example). Thanks.

Comment: I think you must use a path similar of how you load your index.html on electron. try with `__dirname `

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When running the `.exe`, the current directory might be different so the relative path will not be correct. As you figured out you need to put together a full path, but rather than `process.resourcesPath` you should use `app.getAppPath()`.

```
let dbFile = path.join(app.getAppPath(), 'app', 'db', 'example.db')
```

This should be give the correct path to the database file. An additional problem you may face is that the `.exe` will typically be packaged with the [Asar](https://github.com/electron/asar) format, which gives read access but not write access. So if you need to write to the database, it may be better to place it elsewhere. There are a number of paths provided by the [electron.app.getPath(name)](https://electron.atom.io/docs/api/app/#appgetpathname) API, so for example you could use `app.getPath("userData")` to get the path provided for per-user application data. In this case your application would have to create the database file at that location.

Comment: I tried your method by adding `app.getAppPath()` to my dbFile. This method works on macOS, but not for Windows. I don't know why ...

Comment: Hmm possibly because Windows uses different path separators. I've edited to let path.join fill in the path separators.

Comment: Somehow, it works suddenly... Anyway, thank you very much for your help! It saves me a lot of time!

Answer (score 0):

I did several attempts and the only one that worked for me was to replace the **app.asar** file with the database file i.e

```
const { app } = window.require('electron').remote;
const appPath = app.getAppPath().replace("app.asar", "db_name.sqlite");
```